# Display results from past 7 days PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I'm trying to do is display articles from the past 30 days, but the code I have in place keeps giving me a mysql_fetch_assoc error which then traces back to my query

This is the code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM table 
                     WHERE DATE (datetime) = (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
                  ORDER BY ID DESC");

while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

Can someone give me pointers on how to actually make the code work properly?  Here is the error

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: Could you tell us the error you're getting, please?

Comment: That warning means your query failed, change "mysql_query(...);" to "mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());" to get more meaningful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE (datetime) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY ID DESC");
```

I've changed two things:

1. Using `DATE_SUB()` to subtract date.
2. Using `>=` instead of just `=` to find all dates in the past week.

Comment: I tried it but it still gives the same mysql fetch assoc error

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the `'`'s on your `WHERE` clause. Instead of

> ```
> WHERE DATE (datetime) = 'CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY'
> ```

try:

```
WHERE DATE (datetime) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                    FROM table 
                    WHERE DATE BETWEEN '" . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('now')) . "' AND '" . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-30 days')) . "' 
                    ORDER BY ID DESC"
);
```

Should get something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2011-07-26' AND '2011-06-26' 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Note that `date('Y-m-d')` is the way that the day is recorded in your database. So change it the way it is like your DB.

Comment: What's the date format in your database ? Edited the code by adding '' between dates