# how to get the records from a table of last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['last']))
 {
    $s=mysql_query("select * from appointment where `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)");
    echo $s;
    while($last=mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
        echo  $last['date'];
        echo $last['doctor'];
    }
 }
```

how to get the records of last 7 days from a table after clicking of button, the field name of date is  "date"

Comment: seems like you have a solution already, at first sight your query looks fine as well. What exactly are the problems you encounter?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/6839029/2460773

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week

Comment: @NitsanBaleli My comment added, isn't it a triplicate? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This buddy!

```
WHERE date <= NOW() AND date >= DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: is there any date format issue, i store data in  01/07/2015 this format. :(

Comment: @RajSuthar it doesn't matter i think so. Just try this

Comment: @RajSuthar if this didn't worked then try DATE_SUB(NOW())

Comment: is not working without any error

Answer (score 1):

Your Query should look like below------

```
SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE `date`>= DATEADD(day, -7, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `appointment` WHERE `date`>= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Use above query for your solution.